# Surface integral and surface normal for flux calculation

Tags: integration

I have a problem where I need to compare analytical and numerical flux around a circular geometry defined by $$x^2+y^2=0.5^2$$

The flux is defined by $grad(u).n$ where I choose u_analytical to be $(x^2+y^2 , 0)$ in 2 dimensions. The $n$ in the formula is the surface normal of the circle so I think it is $$\left< \frac{2x}{\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2}} , \frac{2y}{\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2}}\right>$$

So my numerical flux in $x$ direction is $$\frac{4x^2}{\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2}} + \frac{4y^2}{\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2}}=1$$ but my numerical solution is far from that.

Have I made any fundamental mistakes here?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I now figured this out after reading some other related/similar posts. The easiest way to think is converting surface integral of the flux \int_S (grad(u).n) dS to volume integral \int_V div (grad(u)) dV using divergence theorem. From there I know div (grad(u)) = 4 and dV is the area of the circle = pi*r^2 that makes 4*pi*r^2 is the analytical flux.